# After Varnish Upgrade HTML/JSON Accept not working

Tags: varnish

After the Upgrade varnish 4 -> varnish-6.2.1 an "Accept"-Request does not respond as expected.

IF I make a first request with "Accept: application/json" it returns HTML, on second request and further it works.

With Varnish3, following Snippet made it work - but not with varnish6

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
    # Called after the response headers has been successfully retrieved from the backend.

    if (!beresp.http.Vary) { # no Vary at all
        set beresp.http.Vary = "Accept";
    } elseif (beresp.http.Vary !~ "Accept") { # add to existing Vary
        set beresp.http.Vary = beresp.http.Vary + ", Accept";
    }
}

sub normalize {
    # Normalize the header, remove the port (in case you're testing this on various TCP ports)
    set req.http.Host = regsub(req.http.Host, ":[0-9]+", "");
    # Remove the proxy header (see https://httpoxy.org/#mitigate-varnish)
    unset req.http.proxy;
    # Normalize the query arguments
    set req.url = std.querysort(req.url);

    if (req.http.Accept) {
        if (req.http.Accept ~ "application/json") {
            set req.http.Accept = "application/json";
        } else {
            set req.http.Accept = "text/html";
        }
    }
}
```

Its not the same as, but very similar: [Varnish 3: Accept JSON returns HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51628871/varnish-3-accept-json-returns-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your VCL code and it works fine. The only addition that was required to make the `sub normalize` work is the following:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    call normalize;
}
```

### The PHP test script

I wrote a small test script to replicate the variation behavior at the origin. Here's the code:

```php
<?php
header('Cache-Control: public, s-maxage=3600');
$timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']) && preg_match('/application\/json/',$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'])) {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $obj = new stdClass;
    $obj->timestamp = $timestamp;
    echo json_encode($obj);
} else {
    echo $timestamp;
}
```

If `application/json` is found in the `Accept` header it returns the following output:

```json
{"timestamp":"2021-11-24 07:38:35"}
```

Otherwise it returns the following plain output:

```
2021-11-24 07:38:35
```

### The VCL

Here's the VCL I used for this:

```
vcl 4.1;

import std;

backend default {
    .host = "localhost";
    .port = "8080";
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    # Called after the response headers has been successfully retrieved from the backend.

    if (!beresp.http.Vary) { # no Vary at all
        set beresp.http.Vary = "Accept";
    } elseif (beresp.http.Vary !~ "Accept") { # add to existing Vary
        set beresp.http.Vary = beresp.http.Vary + ", Accept";
    }
}

sub normalize {
    # Normalize the header, remove the port (in case you're testing this on various TCP ports)
    set req.http.Host = regsub(req.http.Host, ":[0-9]+", "");
    # Remove the proxy header (see https://httpoxy.org/#mitigate-varnish)
    unset req.http.proxy;
    # Normalize the query arguments
    set req.url = std.querysort(req.url);

    if (req.http.Accept) {
        if (req.http.Accept ~ "application/json") {
            set req.http.Accept = "application/json";
        } else {
            set req.http.Accept = "text/html";
        }
    }
}

sub vcl_recv {
    call normalize;
}
```

### How to debug if this doesn't work for you?

You can run the following `varnishlog` command to see what's going on:

```
varnishlog -g request -I ReqHeader:Accept -i requrl -i berequrl -I RespHeader:Vary -I BereqHeader:Accept -I BerespHeader:Vary -i vcl_call -i vcl_return
```

Here's some sample `varnishlog` output for a *cash miss* on HTML content:

```
*   << Request  >> 34
-   ReqURL         /test
-   ReqHeader      Accept: */*
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   ReqURL         /test
-   ReqHeader      Accept: text/html
-   VCL_return     hash
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   VCL_call       MISS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   RespHeader     Vary: Accept
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   VCL_return     deliver
**  << BeReq    >> 35
--  BereqURL       /test
--  BereqHeader    Accept: text/html
--  BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
--  VCL_return     fetch
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_RESPONSE
--  BerespHeader   Vary: Accept
--  VCL_return     deliver
```

Here's what happens on a *cache hit* for regular HTML:

```
*   << Request  >> 32800
-   ReqURL         /test
-   ReqHeader      Accept: */*
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   ReqURL         /test
-   ReqHeader      Accept: text/html
-   VCL_return     hash
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   VCL_call       HIT
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   RespHeader     Vary: Accept
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   VCL_return     deliver
```

Even when the HTML version is still in cache an `Accept: application/json` will result in a cache miss:

```
*   << Request  >> 32802
-   ReqURL         /test
-   ReqHeader      Accept:application/json
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   ReqURL         /test
-   ReqHeader      Accept: application/json
-   VCL_return     hash
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   VCL_call       MISS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   RespHeader     Vary: Accept
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   VCL_return     deliver
**  << BeReq    >> 32803
--  BereqURL       /test
--  BereqHeader    Accept: application/json
--  BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
--  VCL_return     fetch
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_RESPONSE
--  BerespHeader   Vary: Accept
--  VCL_return     deliver
```

And the next time, this will cause a hit for JSON output:

```
*   << Request  >> 32805
-   ReqURL         /test
-   ReqHeader      Accept:application/json
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   ReqURL         /test
-   ReqHeader      Accept: application/json
-   VCL_return     hash
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   VCL_call       HIT
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   RespHeader     Vary: Accept
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   VCL_return     deliver
```